# Iterating through array elements in Codeigniter controller

Tags: codeigniter

In php, when we write and execute a query, we use while loop to iterate

```
$sql  = "SELECT username, role FROM studentlogin WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password'";
        $res = mysql_query($sql);

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_NUM)){
                   $uname = $row[0];
                   $stud_role = $row[1];
            }
```

We then use variables $uname and $stud_role somewhere in our code. I'm trying to do something similar in codeigniter but it fails.

```
function studentlogin($username, $password)
    {

        $query = "SELECT username, role FROM studentlogin WHERE username = ? and password = ?";
        $result = $this->db->query($query, array($username, $password));

        if($result->num_rows() == 1)
        {               
            return $result;
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I'm calling this function from controller as follows

```
$data['info'] = $this->student_model->stdentlogin($username, $password);
```

Here comes the problem. I've tried using the same while loop as above, but it doesn't work here. How can i access each of the two values separately in controller? Need some help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning $result, return $result->row_array();

This will return a named hash of the columns you grabbed.   It will be a single element array, so you won't need to loop through it.

For more information on grabbing database data in codeigniter, check out the [database class information](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html).

Answer (score 0):

[`while()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) evaluates an expression as it processes a loop. If the expression evaluates to `TRUE`, the loop continues. If it is `FALSE`, it stops. Not really the best place for this. (Btw, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated in PHP as of now, so I'd really suggest ignoring how they work).

The [CI Database user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/index.html) has lots of handy examples and information about how to retrieve data from your DB. In your case, if you are retrieving a single row, you should use `$result->row()` or `$result->row_array()`, the former will return a `stdClass` object, the latter an associative array.